# React App Starts on localhost but it adds an extra directory for the hosts repository

Tags: reactjs

guys. I'm writing because I can't seem to be able to start my React app from the localhost. My app has been pushed into a repository. Yesterday it seemed to be OK, but now, when I run "npm start" or "npm run start," it opens the application on localhost and adds an extra directory URL to that of my hosts repository. I'm assuming it has to do with the .env file, but I'm not sure.

For security reasons, I can't show you the link, but it's something like this: https://localhost/*hostname*/*hostnamedirectory*

So, I can't even see what I'm doing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Michael Check the directory location where you are executing command  **npm start**

Location should be project home directory like  `/user/project_name> npm start`

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jimmy. But, as I said, the project location where I'm running it is the directory where the project home is. The thing is it starts the development server on localhost and then adds extra directories to the URL, they happen to be the repository's directories.